Acf date picker field format
i use a code snipest to display some records in a table, and export the table to excel , one field is a date picker, if i don't specify the format in the code it is displayed in the d/m/Y format which is what i need but when i export yhe table in excel then it is displayed in m/d/Y format even the excel recognises it as d/m/Y format. I use the bellow code for specifying the format
echo "<td>" . date('d/m/Y',  strtotime($payroll_date)) . ".  </td>";
But while i receive the correct format 8n the Excel, it displays m/d/Y in yhe html table in yhe frontrnd of the site.
Thank you for your help.
